# Python - TWS Api reqMktData of options with delayed mkt data

Tags: python, interactive-brokers, tws

I am trying to quote some options using reqMktData using the delayed data type. I keep receiving:

**Error 200**, reqId 108: **No security definition has been found for the request**, contract: Contract(secType='OPT', symbol='qqq', lastTradeDateOrContractMonth='20220916', strike=292.5, right='C', exchange='SMART', currency='USD')

My code:

```
    ib.reqMarketDataType(3)
    op_contract = Contract()
    op_contract.symbol = asset_ticker
    op_contract.secType = 'OPT'
    op_contract.exchange = option_exchange
    op_contract.currency = currency
    op_contract.right = 'C'
    op_contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = date
    op_contract.strike = strike
    ib.qualifyContracts(op_contract) #it does find a conID, unique per strike.
    mkt_data_op = ib.reqMktData(op_contract)
```

Am I mising anything? Contract seems ok as I can query historical information...

To make it clearer: I have no data subscription - that is why I am using delayed data (works fine with stocks), trying the cake before buying it ;)

Comment: Were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the exchange to 'BOX'